# Can I combine two 15amp circuits to get one 30amp outlet?

Tags: electrical, receptacle

So I've always wanted to get into crypto mining and recently found someone selling a used asic miner. I've done the math and it would be extremely profitable, unfortunately it requires 2500w of power to run.

What I'm wondering is if there's a safe way to take the power from two different outlets and combine them into one plug, the opposite of a splitter I suppose. Would there be any problem with taking the output of two 120v 15amp outlets and combining it into one 120v 30amp output? Obviously they would have to be on two different circuit breakers/fuses but apart from this I don't see any problem with my idea but wanted to ask other for their opinion.

Would the combined output instead become 240v 30amp? Any electricians thoughts would be much appreciated.

Comment: There is a hack where you can have two 120 outlets and combine them for for 240.  Will give you 240 at 15 amps(or 20 amps), but is for temporary use(minutes) only.  You really should put in a dedicated circuit with the proper wire gauges and breakers for this, since it will be running 24/7 to be safe(not burning down the house).

Comment: What does the actual nameplate say about the required voltage?

Comment: You must have very cheap electricity to consider a single asic miner to be potentially "extremely profitable".  If it was that profitable, ask yourself why the person you bought it from was selling it.  If the profit sounds too good to be true, it probably is.

Comment: I'm not sure if it would work, but you could connect the live wires together and the neutral wires together. Just be sure the two plugs are on the same half of the phase.

Comment: No, it would not be profitable.

Answer (score 5):

The key number here is **2500 W**.

You can't combine 2 x 15A to get 1 x 30A. Even if you could, it wouldn't work the way you think it would work, because it would become 120V x 30A. But you can't do that because code simply does not allow it. There are some very limited circumstances, with **huge** circuits where this is allowed. But not with typical 15A - 50A circuits.

However, you don't need 240V x 30A. What you actually need is 125% of 2500W (continuous usage requires 125% rated capacity). 2,500 x 1.25 = 3,125 W. At 240V, that is 13A. Which means you can fit this on a 240V 15A circuit.

Typical US wiring has two wires plus ground (and past this one mention, we're ignoring ground - you always have to have it). Wire size is based on current = Amperes. A 15A circuit, *whether 120V or 240V*, needs 14 AWG or larger wire. A 20A circuit needs 12 AWG or larger. To consider worst case, we'll assume you have 14 AWG wire (i.e., can't upgrade to 20A). That is one of two possibilities:

- Individual wires (e.g., black and white) in conduit. If that's the case, you can't actually turn it into a 240V circuit, but you can replace the white wire with a colored (black, red, blue, etc. - anything but white, gray or green) wire and make it a 240V circuit.
- Cable with black and white wires. If that's the case (most common in residential wiring outside Chicago and a few other places) then you can mark the white wire on both ends to reuse it as a hot wire for a 240V circuit.

So after either marking or replacing the white wire, you connect the two hot wires to a **double 15A breaker** (not two random individual breakers) and on the other end you replace the NEMA 5-15 receptacle with a [NEMA 6-15 receptacle](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Leviton-15-Amp-Commercial-Grade-Grounding-Single-Outlet-White-5029-W/301207438) which is readily available at any hardware store or electrical supply house (the same place you get that 240V double breaker):

[image: nema 6-15 receptacle]

There is one more technical code issue (not safety, but still code) which is that by doing this you will be effectively removing one of the "usual" 120V receptacles. There are various code requirements for maximum distance between receptacles depending on the type of room, location of doors, etc. If replacing this receptacle causes you to not have receptacles in a place where you should, that is a code violation.

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely not! Do not combine 120V circuits!

### The US *[is a 240V country](https://youtu.be/jMmUoZh3Hq4)*

Just *permanently convert* a 120V circuit to 240V.

Your bitcoin miner has a power supply that will happily accept either 120V or 240V.

- At 120V, 2500W is hard because it needs 21 amps, and wiring is just not made for that.
- At 240V, 2500W is only 10.5 amps.  All wall wiring can handle that, it just needs to have its wall sockets changed and placed it on a 240V breaker at the service panel.

You must change the receptacles to 240V receptacles.  It would be disastrous if someone plugged many 120V appliances into a 240V socket, so do not simply leave 120V sockets energized at 240V.   Many people are lazy and/or task-focused, and don't want to bother with details like this, but that is essential to not killing people.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly from a physics point of view if fed from the same leg it could create a 120v 30A circuit, creating a "ring" circuit *similar* to ring circuits in used in some other parts of the world.

From an NEC viewpoint that would be absolutely illegal, we don't provide point of attachment overcurrent protection for each receptacle on the circuit to insure that excessive current is not available during a fault. Also if you just created a contraption that just plugged into unmodified circuits if you unplugged one cord the prongs would be live.

If fed from separate legs with the wires in the same cable or conduit in a "multiwire branch circuit" configuration you could create and install a 15A 240v receptacle. There are several i's to dot and t's to cross to legally create this configuration.

Answer (score 0):

A 15A 120v circuit provides 1800 watts. So two of them would be 3600 watts (30A total). The catch is you need these to be on different phases to use them with the same neutral (this is a non-starter with two circuits and two neutrals). There is also a way for devices to consume 240v without a neutral (requires balanced loads). NEC is going to require these to be on a double-breaker with a common trip.

The next question is what they mean by 240v. There's two ways to get that. We've already covered the first: two 120v circuits sharing a neutral. The other is just plain old 240v service. Most of the world runs on 240v service and a significant chunk of that runs on 50Hz. US split-phase runs at 60Hz. That's not a big deal for motors, but it's a **very** big deal for computers. Hopefully you bought one that will accept the split-phase 240v at 60Hz (some power supplies will take both, but be sure to check).  If you need that un-split 240v, you may also be out of luck in the US, as you won't be able to use, say, a UK "G" receptacle in US wiring. You'll need a transformer of some sort.